# Agda: Function Parsing error

Tags: parsing, agda

I'm new to agda, and following a simple example in the book little MLer. Could anyone help me to figure out why the compiler gives me a parsing error?

Thank you

```
data Shish (a : Set) : Set where
  Bottom : a → Shish a
  Onion : Shish a → Shish a
  Lamb : Shish a → Shish a
  Tomato : Shish a → Shish a

data Rod : Set where
  Dagger : Rod
  Fork : Rod
  Sword : Rod

data Plate : Set where
  Gold-plate : Plate
  Silver-plate : Plate
  Brass-plate : Plate

what_bottom : Shish (a : Set) → Bool
what_bottom (Bottom x) → x
what_bottom (Onion x) → what_bottom x
what_bottom (Lamb x) → what_bottom x
what_bottom (Tomato x) → what_bottom x



/Volumes/Little/mko_io/cat/tmp/mler.agda:54,24-24
        /Volumes/Little/mko_io/cat/tmp/mler.agda:54,24: Parse error
        :<ERROR>
         Set) → Bool
        what_bottom (Bott...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type definitions are properly defined, but this is not the way one defines functions in Agda. A good starting tutorial is [Dependent types at work](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/DependentTypesAtWork.pdf)

Functions are defined with the equal sign.

```
id : {A : Set} → A → A
id a = a
```

Moreover, the dependent type must be declared before like so either implicitly or explicitly.

```
what_bottom : {A : Set} → Shish A → ...
```

Lastly, that function cannot be defined with a return type `Bool`. It can have type `a` though.

Comment: `{A : Set}` is a new type notion for me, but it seems to be like a clear notion. and thanks for pointing me to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional syntactic point, in Agda, underscores are placeholders for mixfix arguments: `what_bottom` is a mixfix name with one parameter between `what` and `bottom`. So you'll end up with a function that you'd use as `what (Onion $ Lamb $ Bottom) bottom` which is probably not what you intended. Just call it `whatBottom` or `what‿bottom` if you're feeling extra.